# How to draw route on google map with the help of latitude and longitude?

Tags: android

I want to display route direction on google map with the help of longitude and latitude. I have tried some code but it gives me an error message in direction API

> This API project is not authorized to use this API.

I'm not able to enable the direction API with the free trial

My code snippet

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

    if (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        //LatLng sydney = new LatLng(lat, lon);
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(lat, lon);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Current Location"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        // mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    } else {
        requestPermission(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }



    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

            if (markerPoints.size() > 1) {
                markerPoints.clear();
                mMap.clear();
            }

            // Adding new item to the ArrayList
            markerPoints.add(latLng);

            // Creating MarkerOptions
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position of the marker
            options.position(latLng);

            if (markerPoints.size() == 1) {
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            } else if (markerPoints.size() == 2) {
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            }

            // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
            mMap.addMarker(options);

            // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
            if (markerPoints.size() >= 2) {
                LatLng origin = (LatLng) markerPoints.get(0);
                LatLng dest = (LatLng) markerPoints.get(1);

                // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                downloadTask.execute(url);
            }

        }
    });




}
```

---

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        String data = "";

        try {
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();


        parserTask.execute(result);

    }
}
```

---

```
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();;
        lineOptions.width(2);
        lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        // Traversing through all the routes
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);
            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                points.add(position);
            }
            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);

        }
        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        if(points.size()!=0)mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);//to avoid crash
    }
}
```

---

```
private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";
    String mode = "mode=driving";

    String key = "key=" + getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_key);

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + key + "&" + mode;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;


    return url;
}
```

---

```
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.connect();

        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Recently I used direction api in google map without any payment or any details. So make sure you search distance api in console.and then enable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. after creating map and place search key you have enable google maps related libraries in google API console
2. early stage they gave 1000 hit of free quota per day but now everything was payable only,so you have to add your billing account